# How to add a object in the Viewmodel using textbox values in View?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

So i have a mvvm structured application and want to show/edit/add objects to a list in the viewmodel,
i cant seem to understand how i get the values from the textboxes in my viewmodel and create a new paymentmethod to add in the list.

ive looked at lots of threads and some seem to work but not when implement the given answers in my own

```
    class PaymentMethod : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PaymentMethod(string name, double fixedRate, double variableRate)
    {
        Name = name;
        FixedRate = fixedRate;
        VariableRate = variableRate;
    }

    private string name;
    private double fixedrate;
    private double variablerate;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }
    public double FixedRate
    {
        get
        {
            return fixedrate;
        }
        set
        {
            fixedrate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("fixedrate");
        }
    }
    public double VariableRate
    {
        get
        {
            return variablerate;
        }
        set
        {
            variablerate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("variablerate");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
    class PaymentMethodViewModel
{
    private IList<PaymentMethod> _paymentMethods;

    public PaymentMethodViewModel()
    {
        _paymentMethods = new List<PaymentMethod>
        {
            new PaymentMethod("bancontact",0.5,1),
            new PaymentMethod("ideal",0.29,0),
        };
    }
    public IList<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods
    {
        get { return _paymentMethods; }
        set { _paymentMethods = value; }
    }

    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater();
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }
    private class Updater : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members  

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

xaml

```
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="68*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="329*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="Paymentmethodgrid" Margin="4,178,12,13" ItemsSource="{Binding PaymentMethods}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fixed rate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FixedRate}"  Width="80" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Variable rate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VariableRate}" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Label Content="Name&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
    <Label Content="Fixed Rate&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,334" Name="label2" />
    <Label Content="Variable Rate&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,72,0,303" x:Name="label2_Copy" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,10,0,0" Name="txtUserId" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=Paymentmethodgrid,Path=SelectedItem.Name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,45,0,0" x:Name="txtUserId_Copy" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=Paymentmethodgrid,Path=SelectedItem.FixedRate}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,80,0,0" x:Name="txtUserId_Copy1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=Paymentmethodgrid,Path=SelectedItem.VariableRate}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Button Content="Update" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,40,0,0" Name="UpdatePaymentMethod"   
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"  
            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommad}" Grid.Column="1"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you asking how commands are working? You have `CommandParameter` specifically. Or you can provide other ways in the view model to retrieve "view state" (selected item, mouseovered item, etc.).

Comment: @Sinatr i think i need to check how commands work indeed, can i get the multiple values of the textboxes into one `CommandParameter `? if could link some recources that will be great

Comment: What multiple values? You are editing `SelectedItem`, pass that as command parameter. Or (better) bind `SelectedItem` to a property in view model, so it will be always available.

Comment: @Sinatr what i want to accomplish is add  a button that gets the textbox values and creates a new `paymentmethod` and adds it to the `_paymentMethods ` list so it creates a new item that shows in the list.

Comment: So it's not selected item? Then why are you binding `TextBox` to `SelectedItem`? Create a new property in view model to create new item (like a form, right?) and use that inside command.

Comment: If you are using the same controls to also *edit* selected item, then consider to add new item into the list first, select that item and edit it. Btw, it should be an `ObservableCollection<>` to show changes in collection itself in the view easily.

Comment: thanks @Sinatr , indeed ObservableCollection was neccesary for realtime updating, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding new textboxes that bind to new properties in my Viewmodel, if i click on Add new btn the viewmodel just reads its own properties and ads it to the ObservableCollection list and automatically updates.